# Select row with Distinct max(column value)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

[ExactReplica].[FilteredOpportunityProduct] Table

```
Opportunityid      baseamount
1                  500
1                  500
2                  600
2                  700
```

[ExactReplica].FilteredOpportunity Table

```
Opportunityid   name
1                ABC
2                CDF
```

I want to take the maximum baseamount; however, am facing issue when there exists duplicate of the baseamount, how can I take only one record

My Query

```
  select
     MaxAmount.[baseamount] ,
     c.name


 FROM [ExactReplica].FilteredOpportunity c

 Left JOIN
        (
            SELECT  opportunityid,
                    MAX((baseamount)) baseamount
            FROM    [ExactReplica].[FilteredOpportunityProduct] 
            GROUP BY   opportunityid

        ) MaxAmount ON c.opportunityid = MaxAmount.opportunityid
    inner JOIN
        [ExactReplica].[FilteredOpportunityProduct]  p ON   MaxAmount.opportunityid = p.opportunityid
                    AND MaxAmount.baseamount = p.baseamount
```

Comment: please take a look at this link to know more on how to improve the question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: 1. `inner join` in your example is redundant
2. what you do not like in your request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select max(baseamount) baseamount,a.name
from
(select
     baseamount, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by p.opportunityid,baseamount order by p.baseamount desc) rn,
     c.name

 FROM FilteredOpportunity c
    inner JOIN
        [FilteredOpportunityProduct]  p ON   c.opportunityid = p.opportunityid) a
        where rn=1
        group by a.name
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
baseamount  name
500         ABC
700         CDF
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try below query for expected result, I have executed the below scripts :

## For Table Creation :

CREATE TABLE FILTEREDOPPORTUNITYPRODUCT (
  OPPORTUNITYID INT NULL,
  BASEAMOUNT VARCHAR(24) NULL
  )

CREATE TABLE FILTEREDOPPORTUNITY (
  OPPORTUNITYID INT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR(24) NULL
  )

## Insertion:

INSERT INTO FILTEREDOPPORTUNITYPRODUCT (OPPORTUNITYID,BASEAMOUNT) VALUES
(1,500),(1,500),(2,600),(2,700)

INSERT INTO FILTEREDOPPORTUNITY (OPPORTUNITYID,NAME) VALUES 
(1,'ABC'),(2,'CDF')

## Selection:

SELECT 
        A.OPPORTUNITYID,B.NAME,MAX(BASEAMOUNT) AS BASEAMOUNT 
  FROM FILTEREDOPPORTUNITYPRODUCT AS A
  JOIN FILTEREDOPPORTUNITY AS B
     ON A.OPPORTUNITYID = B.OPPORTUNITYID
  GROUP BY A.OPPORTUNITYID,B.NAME